# Jhipster - Configuring Email with Zoho - Error 553 Relaying disallowed

Tags: email, installation, smtp, jhipster, zoho

I am new to Jhipster and trying to configure zoho and I am getting errors.

My setting in /myjhipsterapplicationname/src/main/resources/config/application-dev.yml

```
mail:
host: smtp.zoho.com
port: 587
username: ****@myCustomDomainOnZoho.com
password: ******   // My password for the above email  
protocol: smtp
tls: true
properties.mail.smtp:
auth: true
starttls.enable: true
ssl.trust: smtp.zoho.com
```

Errors, I am receiving

```
2017-03-02 21:15:13.421  WARN 6192 --- [ints-Executor-2] com.nectotech.com.service.MailService    : E-mail could not be sent to user 'asif@nectotech.com'
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed to close server connection after message failures; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 Relaying disallowed as breakpoints@localhost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following and it worked.

1. Go to /myjhipsterapplicationname/src/main/resources/config/application-dev.yml
2. Search for

   mail: # specific JHipster mail property, for standard properties see MailProperties

   from:
3. Replace the value of property from: with your SMTP outgoing email address